# Intel XDk and Restful API's

Tags: asp.net, rest, mobile, intel-xdk

I have developed a sample API (as per tutorial by tutecentral resful api for android) This works fine in test)
I now need to develop a front end that will perform various activities using this API for learning purposes. I would prefer to use Intel XDK for the front end. The [demo](http://www.tutecentral.com/restful-api-for-android-part-2/) is done based on Android ADT plugin.
Please advise how I should proceed.
My ulmate goal is to develop a mobile app for both Android and IOS that can upload images, message, etc and update a SQL database. I also need to retrieve data and images back to the mobile device. The demo [in other question](http://www.tutecentral.com/restful-api-for-android-part-1/) seems to provide applicable foundation for the API side. I now need to perform this from Intel XDK unless you want to recommend another approach. I am coming from an ASP.NET and Windows forms background. I am a beginner with Intel XDK and Javascript but advanced in ASP.NET, and C#

regards

Comment: Your question is very broad.  Do you have a more specific technical question?  I don't mean to be flippant, but if your question is really "How do I proceed", I would recommend getting some good books on Web development and Javascript.  A more appropriate question might be something like "How do I convert a restful JSON response into a Javascript Object", "How do I capture photos in a cordova web app".

Comment: Can't you just implement a restful webapp and make simple http calls using javascript? simple and cross platform.

Comment: Thanks for these responses.

Comment: Thanks for these responses. OldGeeksGuide-I have completed a working API (ASP.NET) that accesses SQL successfully. I have also done a console app C# that consumes the API and this is working perfectly. I have since converted the C# version to java my problem is now how to proceed specifically related to Intel XDK. Where to put the API code, the 'calling code' similar to the console app preferably from a button, how to populate listview with code received back from API. Will gladly get the books if you provide a link :) @Paizo-what you are suggesting sounds good. Please provide link to example

Answer (score 0):

Here are some [Tutorials](https://software.intel.com/en-us/search/site/field_tags/intel-xdk-42296/type/bds_video)  to get you started in Intel XDK, and here is some [information on integrating web services in Intel XDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/using-web-services#service_createown). Here you will find the [documentation on the 3 files created in Intel XDK for the web service](https://github.com/mashery/iodocs). These are the apiconfig.js, yourService.js and yourService.json files.